# Function returning a generic array

Tags: scala

I have one issue for a function that I wrote about the conversion of one `Array[Byte]` to a `Array[T]`. The function in question :

```
def getPoints[T](bytes : Array[Byte]) : Array[T] = {
      val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)
      byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
      val data = Array.ofDim[T](bytes.length / biosRecord.byteEncoding)
      if(biosRecord.byteEncoding == 2) {
        byteBuffer.asShortBuffer.get(data)
        data
      } else if(biosRecord.byteEncoding == 4) {
        byteBuffer.asIntBuffer().get(data)
        data
      } else null
    }
```

`biosRecord` is a case class with a int field (`byteEncoding`).

I know there is two problems in this code :

1. To return a generic array, I need to use `Manifest`.
2. In the first `if` branch, the inferred type is `Array[Short]` and in the second one is `Array[Int]`. This is why I tried to use a generic type `T` but it not works.

What I get at the compilation time :

```
[error]   (x$1: Array[Short])java.nio.ShortBuffer <and>
[error]   (x$1: Int)Short
[error]  cannot be applied to (Array[T])
[error]         byteBuffer.asShortBuffer.get(data)

[error]   (x$1: Array[Int])java.nio.IntBuffer <and>
[error]   (x$1: Int)Int
[error]  cannot be applied to (Array[T])
[error]         byteBuffer.asIntBuffer().get(data)
```

What do I need to do in order to make this generic function compiles ?

Comment: I see two problems, `byteBuffer.asShortBuffer.get(data)` get here takes an int or an `Array[Short]` but your array is generic, second `ofDim` needs an implicit `ClassTag` for your `T`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature `def getPoints[T](bytes : Array[Byte]) : Array[T]` means that the *caller* can decide what `T` is. For instance, by calling:

```
val myResult = getPoints[String](myBytes)
```

I'm making `getPoints` return an `Array[String]`, *regardless* of the value of `myBytes`.

In other words - **what you're trying to do is not possible**. You cannot parameterize a method's type based on "decisions" inside the method *body*.

Perhaps what you want to do here is use **the best common type** that is a superclass of all possible return types. In this case:

```
def getPoints(bytes : Array[Byte]) : Array[AnyVal] = {
    // can return Array[Int], Array[Short]...
}
```

This way, the caller can't force the type, and doesn't *know* the type, all they know is that it's one of the subclasses of `AnyVal`.

Comment: I understood and to fix this error, I use an ADT. Thank you for your explanation